# How to use redis-cli with Redis on Docker?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-cli

Run Redis in Docker

File `docker-compose.yml`

```yml
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

```
docker pull redis
docker-compose up
docker-compose up -d
docker container ls
telnet localhost 6379
```

How to connect to Redis server with `redis-cli` ?

Comment: You should just be able to run it normally, since you've published the Redis port 6379 out of the container on its normal port number.  What happens if you just run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run attach to docker container and use `redis-cli` directly.

This command will attach you to the container's shell

```sh
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/sh
```

Then you can use redis-cli just like it installed directly on the host system

Comment: I run `docker exec -t c53e7198f414 /bin/sh` then I cannot type anything. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95659826-fa9e5580-0b4d-11eb-82f3-94504bac3d67.png How to typing?

Comment: You need to use cli arg `-it`  which means interactive pseudo-tty. without `-i` you cannot perform any interaction with executed command.


UPDATE: docs reference for `docker exec` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/#options